# Android problem: null exception error when dereferencing CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm running into a strange problem.

I have a CheckBox defined in a resource file:

When trying to see if the checkbox is checked or not, I use the following code:

CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check1);

when I execute the following:

if (cb1.isChecked())
{
}

I get a null exception error. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  An important part of how Stackoverflow works is marking one of the answers to your questions as the "correct" answer.  You should go back through your previous questions and check the green checkbox next to one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`cb1` is null, which means that `findViewById()` couldn't find the view whose ID you specified. Do you have a `CheckBox` in your layout file with `android:id="@+id/check1"`?

Comment: Yes I have the following in my xml layout file:

Comment: <CheckBox
          android:id="@+id/check1"
          android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
          android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>

Comment: Are you calling `setContentView(R.id.<nameoflayout>)` before the `findViewById()` line? If your layout file lives in `layout/mylayout.xml`, you would have to call `setContentView(R.id.mylayout)`.